# Trying to toggle a div size

Tags: jquery

I put everything into one html doc just in case it might be the css that's causing problems... I have 4 green boxes I made using divs and css. I would like them to grow in size when clicked -- Maybe just from 80x80px to 100x100px or something like that. Right now the jQuery code in there is code I took from an answer to someone else's question-- I am really new to jQuery, and am having a lot of trouble with it. Any help would be appreciated!!

```
<html>
<head>
<title>For testing</title>

<style type="text/css">
#green_box_container {
    float: left;
    padding: 0px;
    margin-left: 345px;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}

#green_box1 {
    background-color: #070;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#green_box2 {
    background-color: #070;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#green_box3 {
    background-color: #070;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}

#green_box4 {
    background-color: #070;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    height: 80px;
    width: 80px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
}
</style>

<script src="jquery-1.9.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#green_box_container a").click(function() {
    var $this = $(this),
        val = $this.height() == 200 ? '50px' : '200px';
    $this.stop().animate({
        width: val,
        height: val
    }, "slow");
});
});
</script>

</head>

<body>

<div id="green_box_container">
<a href="#"><div id="green_box1"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box2"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box3"></div></a>
<a href="#"><div id="green_box4"></div></a>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: what is your problem? nothing is happening?

Comment: When I preview in browser (I have tried Firefox and Chrome) and click on the divs, nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to animate the `div` inside the `a` (anchor). To this end you can simply apply the animate function to the interior `div` as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#green_box_container a").click(function () {
        var $this = $(this),
            val = $this.height() == 200 ? '50px' : '200px';
        $this.find("div").stop().animate({
            width: val,
            height: val
        }, "slow");
    });
});
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate the idea: http://jsfiddle.net/bHyHS/

Comment: Thank you!! Can you tell me what the "== 200 ? '50px' : '200px';" does and what the "val"s do? It's working great on the jsfeddle.net link, but I was wondering if I could change it to make the size change a bit less drastic. I would also like it if when you clicked one green div, the others returned to their original size. Thank you for your quick response and patience with me!! --- Also, when I copied your jQuery code into DreamWeaver and then previewed my page in Firefox, I didn't get the same results as on the jsfiddle page... Is it my browser that's been the trouble all along???

Comment: For some reason this works great on jsfiddle.net but not in my browser?? Is it because I am using jquery 1.9.1 ?

Comment: @BrookeBenson I doubt it's a browser thing. I'd make sure jquery is loaded first (jsfiddle includes it for you).  In `== 200 ? '50px' : '200px';` The `?` followed by `:` is called a ternary operation, and it means the same as `if ...==200 then '50px' else '200px'`. Btw, it made no sense to attach the event on the anchor, I updated the fiddle, to apply it to the inner div: http://jsfiddle.net/bHyHS/2/

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the complete example.  I tested this locally and it seems your jquery selector is where you are having the problem.

By saying giveme $("#green_box_container a"), you are grabbing all the anchor tags withing the green_box_container.  Then, you try to resize the anchors and not the actual divs withing the anchor tags.

To select all the divs within the anchors within the green_box_container, you simply need to add another level to your jquery selector as follows:

$("#green_box_container a div")

Hope this helps.

Comment: Still nothing when I preview in browser, I am afraid. :( Thanks for the suggestion though!